# MVC 3 - System.byte[] output instead of showing image

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I complete index.cshtml file looks like this...

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMyApplication.Models.SubProductCategory2>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

 <p>
   some javascripts code
 </p>
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="color: #F5FFFA; 
  font-family: Constantia, Georgia, serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 
  14px; background-color: #D2691E;" size="15" />

 <table id="admin_table">
 <thead>
  <tr>
     <th></th>
      <th>
        CategoryName
      </th>
      <th>
        SubCategoryName
      </th>
      <th>
       Picture
      </th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
 <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { 
         id=item.SubProductCategoryID }) |
       @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { 
         id=item.SubProductCategoryID })
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.ProductCategory.CategoryName
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.SubCategoryName
    </td>
       <td>
           <img alt="@Html.Encode(item.SubProductCategoryID)" 
           src='@(Url.Action(("Image")) + item.SubProductCategoryID)' 
           width="100" height="100" />
      </td>
   </tr>
 }
```

Complelte Create.cshtml file looks this...

```
enter code here
@model MvcMyApplication.Models.ProCat1

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

<h2>Create</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts
/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ProductCategoryL2", FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))

{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>ProCat1</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProductCategoryID", 
        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["CategoryName"]) 
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubCategoryName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SubCategoryName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubCategoryName)
    </div>

   <!-- <div class="editor-field">
    <img alt="Current image" src='@Url.Action("image", new { id = 
    Model.SubProductCategoryID } )' />    
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23"/>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubProductCategoryID)
   </div> -->
     <p>
       <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
 }

 <div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </div>
```

Controller for Create and Image looks like this...

```
enter code here
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        PopulateProductCategoryDropDownList(-1);
        return View();
    }

    private void PopulateProductCategoryDropDownList(object selectedCategory)
    { 
          ViewBag.CategoryName = new SelectList ((from d in db.ProductCategories select d).ToList(), 
          "ProductCategoryID", "CategoryName", selectedCategory);
    }

    //
    // POST: /ProductCategoryL2/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "SubProductCategoryID")] SubProductCategory2 Createsubcat2, FormCollection values)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
             Createsubcat2.Picture1 = (new FileHandler()).uploadedFileToByteArray((HttpPostedFileBase)Request.Files[0]);
            }
            db.AddToSubProductCategory2(Createsubcat2);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("/");
        }
        PopulateProductCategoryDropDownList(Createsubcat2.ProductCategoryID);
        return View(Createsubcat2);
    }

 public FileResult Image(int id)
    {

       const string alternativePicturePath = @"/Content/question_mark.jpg";
        SubProductCategory2 product = db.SubProductCategory2.Where(k => k.SubProductCategoryID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        MemoryStream stream;

        if (product != null && product.Picture1 != null)
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream(product.Picture1);
        }
        else // If product cannot be found or product doesn't have a picture
        {
            stream = new MemoryStream();

            var path = Server.MapPath(alternativePicturePath);
            var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path);

            image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        }

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

FileHandler class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

public class FileHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a HttpPostedFileBase into a byte array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public byte[] uploadedFileToByteArray(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        int nFileLen = file.ContentLength;
        byte[] result = new byte[nFileLen];

        file.InputStream.Read(result, 0, nFileLen);

        return result;
    }

 }
```

}

Thanks tvanfosson.

Comment: Why don't you just write `stream = new FileStream(alternativePicturePath)`?

Comment: where do I put stream = new FileStream(alternativePicturePath)?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is totally wrong; you want to call `Url.Action` with an action name and a parameter.

Your `alt` text is also wrong; you're effectively calling `ToString()` on a byte array, which returns `"System.Byte[]"`.

Since your incorrectly generated URL doesn't exist, it's showing the incorrect `alt` text instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `Picture1` is image data, `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Picture1)` isn't what you want. You probably want to call the Image action to display the picture inline.

...code sample coming

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <img alt="Current image" src='@Url.Action("image", new { id = Model.PictureID } )' />    
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" size="23"/>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PictureID)
</div>
```

Then change the create GET method so that it populates the PictureID  instead of the Picture on the model.

Comment: tvanfosson - I don't quite follow when say change the create Get method. Are you refering to the controller? I don't have PictureID column but I do have SubProductCategoryID?

Comment: @Disco - I mean the Create action corresponding to the GET request that shows the creational interface.  It would need to have a model with the id of the picture to display, not the bytes of the image itself.   You can't render the image directly in the view, you have to reference a URL in an image tag.

Comment: I don't seem to graps, because the lack of knowledge I have. In others words I don't know how to. Would it be earier to use JQuery?

Comment: @Disco - jQuery has nothing to do with this.  It's simply a matter of understanding how to put an image on the page.  You have to use an image tag to display an image, there's no other way.

Comment: @tvanfosson - I think I understand What you mean so I have edited the code at the top of thread. I am recieving a error of System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @disco - you don't show the action where you are loading the page only the action that is posted back to.  Are you setting the model in the action that responds to the get request?

Comment: @tvanfosson - I have update the top tread. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually I am going to close this off. I believe there is some sytax error with FileResult Image method in the controller. I will attempt alternative, more simple appoarch.